# Safari + VoiceOver: Screenreader is not announcing the whole text inside Div instead its announcing "2 more items, groups"

Tags: html, angular, safari, accessibility, voiceover

This issue is occurring in Safari only.

1. open NVDA voiceover
2. click on input
3. press tab
4. Press arrow down

Expected: it should announce the whole text inside div tag.

Result: it is announcing first div text + 2 more items, group.

NOTE: In Chrome, it is working as expected.

```html
<input />
<div>
  <div tabindex="0">
    <div>student1</div>
    <div>
    <span>ems</span>
    <span>111111</span>
    </div>
    <div><button aria-label="student1">student1
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div tabindex="0">
  <div>student2</div>
  <div>
  <span>ems</span>
  <span>111112</span>
  </div>
  <div><button aria-label="student2">plus
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the entirety of the markup? Why is there a `tabindex`? It would help if we know what you are trying to achieve (as answers will be very different depending on what the intended control / widget does) but at the moment the screen reader appears to be doing its best at parsing a load of information that needs some semantics adding and guessing it is a group.

Comment: Yes, it is entirely of the markup. And tabindex has given for the accessibility to achieve the whole div if we remove the tabindex then tab button will go to button area, not the whole div.
Suppose we have the list then we want to access the whole text then button.

Comment: The problem is that by adding `tabindex="0"` you now have an area that will appear to be interactive (as you can focus it) but has no functionality. If the design brief **insists** that the whole card be focused you would be better removing `tabindex="0"` and instead using `focus-within` in your CSS so that when the button is focused the whole "card" has an outline. Not ideal but far better than having a random focusable element that has no interactivity. This will also probably fix your "groups" issue.

Comment: Screen reader users will be able to access the info (although it looks like it should be a `<ul>` and `<li>` from the small snippet shown.) so it will then be more accessible. If you want to link to a fiddle with some CSS that shows the end design I can help you improve the markup (as at the moment it isn't clear what information goes where so I am not sure how best to guide you as context affects what markup to use).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, before considering the actual problem, you have two focusable zones within one another.
The `<div tabindex="0">` itself contains a `<button>`.

You shouldn't do so. It isn't well defined, and it's hard to define, what should happen to focus, and by extension also to click.

Should one consider that the div still focused when going to the button ? When clicking or pressing enter on the button, should the div also react or not ?
This is the pypical kind of question where browser don't all agree because it isn't defined in the standard. It isn't defined in the standard because there is no answer that can, or should universally apply. It's **undefined behavior**.

It might well happen that, once you have fixed this, your original problem will be gone.